# Using linear regression and Poisson for a data set

Tags: r, regression, self-study, poisson-regression

We are asked to perform linear regression with a data set. The lecturer has stated that we can choose our own data set as long as it has 20 rows with 4 columns.

Using R, I have typed up a data set of my hours studied across four papers over 20 days. The numbers here represent blocks which are 25 mins. 1 block = 25 mins, 2 blocks = 50 mins etc.

Data set:

> Data

```
Stats PDC LDD InfoSci
4   0   4       2
0   4   4       2
2   4   2       1
2   1   0       0
2   1   0       0
1   2   2       0
0   3   1       0
0   0   4       0
3   0   4       0
2   4   0       2
2   6   0       4
2   1   2       4
4   1   2       2
6   2   1       2
4   0   4       4
0   1   2       2
0   1   2       6
1   4   0       2
2   4   0       4
2   2   0       4
```

I have used a regression analysis using r to see if there is any correlation between hours spent studying Stats and hours spent studying PDC.

```
 fit<-lm(Stats~PDC,data=Data)
```

I have fitted a linear model with y = Stats and x = PDC. This gives me poor results of a p-value: 0.3557 with an $R^2$ value of 0.04755.

I have tried using logs to increase the $R^2$ value.

```
lm(log(Stats)~log(PDC),data=Data)
```

This doesn't work though.

My questions is what are other ways to increase the $R^2$ value?

Comment: "We are asked to perform linear regression with a data set." This task seems not well defined. I suggest, you first plot the data `plot(Stats~PDC,data=Data)`. When presented with this plot, most people would readily agree that the regression result is correct: The data does not indicate any relationship between these two variables. However, I assume your teacher wants you to do multiple regression taking into account all information in the data set. Also note that for dependent variables that are counts you should use a generalized linear model such as Poisson regression.

Comment: 1. I would not be likely to use ordinary Poisson regression; the "stats" variable is not really a count but a discretized duration (though I could perhaps make an argument for some kind of count process), it wouldn't seem likely to have the conditional variance equal to the conditional mean. (It doesn't matter what the IVs are for Poisson regression, but I'd regard all of them the same).  2. Searching for a way to "increase R" is akin to significance hunting. What's the purpose of seeking a high $R^2$, rather than seeking to find a good description of the relationship, if any?

Comment: As an example, I can take a weakly correlated pair of variables, generated from a linear regression model (with all assumptions holding). It's easy to set it up so that the correlation between $e^x$ and $e^y$ is a fair bit higher than that between x and y but the relationship between $e^x$ and $e^y$  is not linear  and the error term is no longer additive nor homoskedastic nor normal, while a linear regression model between y and x is actually the data generating model - the linear regression on the exponentiated variables has higher $R^2$, but I'd regard it as a worse model